# Unexpected lock protocol: Expected 3, found 49

Tags: grails, gradle

I am using Grails 3 to make an application. I have the grails sdk in my path. When I run the

```
grails
```

command, under my project dir, I get the following error:

```
Error Error initializing classpath: Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 49.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 49.
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockStateAccess.readState(LockStateAccess.java:74)
```

if I move to a different dir, that does not have the project, and try to run the grails command it works. However, when trying to create-app, it fails miserably. Any idea as to what files can be placed on lock? I have attached a picture of my working dir.

[image]

Note, I am on Windows 7, 64BIT. I have attempted restarting and pulling down a clean project, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh, it turns out that I had two versions of the Groovy SDK installed. Removing both of them, and only ensuring there is one, resolved the issue.